# Is there any way to change data from a matplotlib plot after it has been created and showed?

Tags: python, function, matplotlib

So I have a function that prints me some plot once called, and returns some other data. The code for the plot is this one

```
def somefunction(input):

     x = np.linspace(-5,5,100)
     fig, axs = plt.subplots(2,sharex=True)
     fig.suptitle("Some plots")

     axs[0].plot(x, x**2, "-b", label="square")
     axs[1].plot(x, x**3, "-y", label="cube")

     axs[0].set(ylabel="values")
     axs[1].set(xlabel="Timestamp (common)", ylabel="values")

     axs[0].legend()
     axs[1].legend()
 
     plt.show()
     

     return [1,2,3]
```

Now, what I want to do is to print this plot later again but with additional information. I thought about saving the figure created here as the output of the function. I tried to do this by adding this to the code:

```
def somefunction(input):

    x = np.linspace(-5,5,100)
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(2,sharex=True)
    fig.suptitle("Some plots")

    axs[0].plot(x, x**2, "-b", label="square")
    axs[1].plot(x, x**3, "-y", label="cube")

    axs[0].set(ylabel="values")
    axs[1].set(xlabel="Timestamp (common)", ylabel="values")

    axs[0].legend()
    axs[1].legend()

    plt.show()
    fig_out = fig

    return [1,2,3], fig_out
```

and then later I can just obtain the figure in the second component of the output of the function and change it as I want. Like:

```
figure = somefunction(input)[1]
#now perform any wanted changes in the plot and plot again
ax0 = figure.axes[0]
ax0.text(3, 8, 'New text updated in the figure', style='italic',
    bbox={'facecolor': 'red', 'alpha': 0.5, 'pad': 10})

plt.show()
```

This doesn't work. The figure is indeed, saved in the second component of the output, but it doesn't let me change anything about it. It's just there, and I can't change it, nor plot any changes made to the figure.

I also tried saving the axes instead of the figure, but same story. I can't seem to find a way to edit this plot after it was created. Is it even possible?

Comment: Your code sample is incomplete (does not run as is). Please provide a reproducible code so people understand your problem fast and can work on it immediately.

Comment: It is possible to update some data, but as others point out, you should provide minimum code to run.

Comment: First, your `somefunction ` returns `output` which is what? You need to have the same object, the figure and axes to apply the change to.

Comment: @KotaMori sorry, I did not put reproducible code. Now the code is reproducible. In any case, the reproducible parts are not important. The numerical outputs/inputs of the function do not really take part in the problem.

Comment: The `matplotlib.pyplot.draw()` might be what you are looking for (https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.draw.html).  `This is used to update a figure that has been altered, but not automatically re-drawn.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine, if you don't try to show both plots at once. There are multiple options to solve it, for instance:

**Option 1:** show the plot at the end

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def somefunction(input):
    x = np.linspace(-5,5,100)
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(2,sharex=True)
    fig.suptitle("Some plots")

    axs[0].plot(x, x**2, "-b", label="square")
    axs[1].plot(x, x**3, "-y", label="cube")

    axs[0].set(ylabel="values")
    axs[1].set(xlabel="Timestamp (common)", ylabel="values")

    axs[0].legend()
    axs[1].legend()

    #plt.show() #<- DO NOT USE IT NOW

    return [1,2,3], fig

my_fig = somefunction(input)[1]
ax0 = my_fig.axes[0]
ax0.text(3, 8, 'New text updated in the figure', style='italic', bbox={'facecolor': 'red', 'alpha': 0.5, 'pad': 10})

plt.show()
```

**Option 2:** use `block=False` to indicate to wait until all figures are returned

```
def somefunction(input):
    x = np.linspace(-5,5,100)
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(2,sharex=True)
    fig.suptitle("Some plots")

    axs[0].plot(x, x**2, "-b", label="square")
    axs[1].plot(x, x**3, "-y", label="cube")

    axs[0].set(ylabel="values")
    axs[1].set(xlabel="Timestamp (common)", ylabel="values")

    axs[0].legend()
    axs[1].legend()

    plt.show(block=False) #<- USE BLOCK=FALSE

    return [1,2,3], fig

my_fig = somefunction(input)[1]
ax0 = my_fig.axes[0]
ax0.text(3, 8, 'New text updated in the figure', style='italic', bbox={'facecolor': 'red', 'alpha': 0.5, 'pad': 10})

plt.show()
```